# Insertar en Spinner valores de SQL Android

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

Realizo una select a una tabla y me devuelve una fila completa. Esa fila la introduzco en un objeto. Mi intencion es la de recoger el valor y inflar un spinner para que si encuentra por ejemplo en la select: "8" me genere un spinner con valores del 1 al 8. He encontrado varias guias por internet pero soy incapaz de hacerlo. ¿Alguna ayuda?

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/manejadorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewVnt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:text="Vender:" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Sp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></Spinner>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonInvertirTick"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/success" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_amazon_venta);

    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Sp); 
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTextoV);

    opera = new OperacionesBaseDatos();
    carteraObj = opera.leerCartera(10);

    if (carteraObj.getCantidad() > 0) {

        textView.setText("Dispone de " + carteraObj.getCantidad() + " acciones de Amazon INC con un coste de " + carteraObj.getPrecio() + " de media. Actualmente se cotiza a la acción");
    } else {

        textView.setText("No dispone de ninguna accion en propieded de esta entidad");
    }
}
```

Los valores a insertar en el spinner se obtendrian con carteraObj.getCantidad() e iria dentro del if (carteraObj.getCantidad() > 0)

Comment: Que es carteraObj, un List o array???

Comment: Un objeto con su constructor y sus getter y seter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tendrías que hacer es iterar hasta llegar a ese valor cantidad y construir un arreglo (por simplicidad sugiero Strings) con los valores.

```
String[] valores = new String[cantidad];
for(int x =0; i< cantidad ; i++){
valores[x]=""+x;
}
```

y usar ese array para armar el adapter que vas a setear en el spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        valores, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```